# Define the from to send an email

Tags: laravel

I have this code to send an email to the conference organizer:

```
  Mail::to($conference->
  organizer_email)
  ->send(new UserNotification($conference, $message, $subject));
```

And it works but do you know how to also define the from? For example the email should be from the authenticated user to the conference organizer. Do you know what is necessary for that?

UserNotification:

```
class UserNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $conference;
    public $message;
    public $subject;



    public function __construct(Conference $conference, $message, $subject)
    {
        $this->conference = $conference;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }


    public function build()
    {

        return $this->markdown('emails.userNotification', [
            'message' => $this->message,
            'subject' => $this->subject
        ]);
    }
}
```

Updated:

Send email with:

```
$user = Auth::user();
Mail::to($conference->organizer_email)
->send(new UserNotification
($conference, $user, $message, $subject));
```

UserNotification:

```
class UserNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $conference;
    public $user;
    public $message;
    public $subject;

    public function __construct(Conference $conference, User $user, $message, $subject)
    {
        $this->conference = $conference;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }
    public function build()
    {
         // shows the auth user email but the email is 
        // sent to the email set in MAIL_USERNAME in .env file
        // instead of sent to the auth user email
        dd($this->user->email);

        return $this->from($this->user->email)->markdown('emails.userNotification', [
            'message' => $this->message,
            'subject' => $this->subject
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$this->from($senderEmail, $senderName)` < accepts two parameters. The sender email and the optional sender name. Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#configuring-the-sender) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. Like that the email is sent to the conference organizer, that is correct, but the from instead of appear the auth user email appears the email configured in the .env file in  theMAIL_USERNAME.

Comment: I didnt understand, which result? It dont appears any error, the issue is that in the email instead of appear the email of the auth user (the email of the user that ent the email) it appears the email defined in the MAIL_USERNAME in .env file..